# AppEngine Logging Limits

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

Are there any limits on the AppEngine application logs? Does google store an unlimited volume of log data? If not, how many entries or how many days of data are stored?

What is the limit on individual logs? I tried to make a very large log and it was truncated. Is the excess data lost or just hidden from the online log viewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logs are like a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), newer data overwrites older data.  I don't believe the actual limits are published.

You can periodically [download](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs) your logs if you need more history.  For a busy app you might need to do this frequently.

Comment: Do you have any links to back this up? If it is limited I need to know how often to pull down the logs.

Comment: @mchr,  There are a few posts in the groups (such as: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/c441f9e435722588/271c6af926b1fc95?lnk=gst&q=log+size#271c6af926b1fc95).  You'll probably need to experiment to figure out how often to pull the logs.  On a busy site you might need to pull every 20 minutes.  On a less-busy site (or with less data logged!) you may only need to pull daily.